# difference between a and a: link and others

Tags: html, css

I know it's a stupid question.

I always wondered what is the difference between:

```
.test a {}
or
.test a:link {}
```

I did several tests, they look the same.

what changes?

Comment: On top of what the existing answers already said so far: Using just `a` as selector will format any `a` elements, whereas `:link` or `a:link` will only apply to those that have a (non-empty) `href` attribute set. (Granted, it is rather rare to have `a` elements without `href`, but sometimes it might occur for various reasons.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**6.6.1.1. The link pseudo-classes: `:link` and `:visited`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited)
>
> User agents commonly display unvisited links differently from
>   previously visited ones. Selectors provides the pseudo-classes `:link`
>   and `:visited` to distinguish them:
>
> - The `:link` pseudo-class applies to links that have not yet been visited.
> - The `:visited` pseudo-class applies once the link has been visited by the user.
>
> After some amount of time, user agents may choose to return a visited
>   link to the (unvisited) ‘`:link`’ state.
>
> The two states are mutually exclusive.

Moreover, adding the `:link` pseudo-class increases the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity):

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count the number of ID selectors in the selector (=a)
> - count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (=b)
> - count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (=c)
> - ignore the universal selector

Comment: marking it as a duplicate and submitting an answer stops anyone else from submitting an answer. This is seen as a monopoly on Stack. Wasn't marking it as a duplicate not enough?

Comment: @Fred-ii- First I searched a bit and found no duplicate, so I posted an answer. Then I remembered having seen the duplicate, so I searched better and found it. If this seems a conflict of interests, I can delete my answer (but first it should be unaccepted).

Comment: Or reopen it. You did write a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

the :link selector is used to style the ***unvisited*** links.  For example, the following would change the font-size of the unvisited links.

```
a:link {
    font-size:14px;
}
```